# How do I get an array from inputs in JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, arrays, select, textinput

I have a group of inputs to get player info:

```
<select name="playerSport" class="playerSport">...</select>
<input type="text" name="playerPosition" class="playerPosition" />
<input type="text" name="playerNumber" class="playerNumber" />
<button id="submit">Submit</submit>
```

There can be n number of each field. I'm using AJAX with this form so I want to pull each field into an array. Have an array for each sport, position, and number.

i've reviewed the examples from these pages:
[jquery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val)
and
[jquery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

i've tried:

```
var sport = $('input[name="playerSport"').val() || [];
var sportList = sport.join(",");

var sport = $('.playerSport').val() || [];
var sportList = sport.join(",");

$('input[name="playerSport"').map().get().join(",");

$('.playerSport').map().get().join(",");
```

these return blank results. Odds are I'm missing something fairly obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: `$('.playerSport').val()` these will return you only one value and not an array then how can you do .join ???

Comment: This is probably not the main problem, but you are missing closing brackets on `$('input[name="playerSport"')` it should be `$('input[name="playerSport"]')` that is on the 1st line and the 7th line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = $.map($(".playerSport,.playerPosition,.playerNumber"), function(el) {
 return $(el).val();
});
// now 'a' is an array containing the values.
```

Comment: ah! I HAVE to do the return. Cool, that did it. I'll select this as the answer once the time runs out. thanks!

Comment: could do the same thing also as `$("...").map(function (el) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to pass a function into `.val()`

```
var values = [];
$(":input").val(function(index, value){
    values.push(value);
});
```

Also you can use `:input` if you want to select all `<select/>`, `<input type="text"/>`, and `<textarea/>` elements.

[**Code example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/M93zS/1/)

Comment: You are abusing the `.val` function. Use `.map` for this. `.val` is intended to set the value for each element to the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` [will return an array](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for an element with multiple values (like a multi-`<select>`), but it does not return an array of values from each element in the selected node set.

You'll need to build up an array in a callback function, possibly using `$.map`.